# Obtain prices for list of stocks

Tags: equities, data, market-data, historical-data, tick-data

I have a spreadsheet with a large number of ticker symbols. Is there any site that can get the current or past (either works) price for each of these stocks in one fell swoop? Paste in the list of stock ticker symbols, and receive a list of their current or past prices as an output.

Doing them one by one would take an eternity in my case, and creating a web scraper is something I'm hoping to avoid if a site out there already has this capability.

Comment: Depending on how large your list is, http://investexcel.net/importing-historical-stock-prices-from-yahoo-into-excel/ may do the trick, though I'm surprised there isn't a canonical source for this. You may try asking on opendata.stackexchange.com as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly suggest Quandl as a great place to start: https://www.quandl.com/tools/excel

Has a lot capabilities for stock look ups and works really well once you've gained some familiarities with it. Can really build out a powerful sheet if you don't need tick data or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

GoogleSheets can query multiple stock data also. Using the built-in functions you can query open, high, low, close prices for a particular date range.

Comment: Which built-in functions? Do you have an example of how I could do this with Google Docs?